# Is ORDER BY time consuming?

Tags: sql, database

I am always wondering if ORDER BY is efficient, because I believe it inevitably need a whole-database scanning, even if the ordering field is indexed.

For example, if I order by created_at and limit 10. I think, because the database cannot know I will order by created_at a priori, it has to sort the whole data and return the first 10 items. Of course if we have an index on created_at, things might be better.

However, even with index, I think we can still run into trouble. For example, I want to sort by a function of a field, say (age^2-age-10). Even if we indexed the age field, the database cannot know what function I will use a priori, so it has to calculate the sqrt on all rows.

Am I wrong? Anyway, could anyone explain to me the workflow behind ORDER BY?

Answer (score 3):

If there is an index that is sorted in the same order as specified in the ORDER BY clause, the database will not need to perform a sort operation. The query optimizer looks for indexes that can speed up your query. It analyzes your SQL query and, in the case of ORDER BY clauses, looks for indexes that have the same order. See [Indexing ORDER BY](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/sorting-grouping/indexed-order-by) for more details.

Some database engines allow indexing computed columns, which would cover the case you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, the database optimizer can take into account the `limit` clause when determining the query plan.  This is most obviously useful with a `limit 1` query, which can be implemented just by keeping track of which row has the extreme value for the columns in the `order by`.  The same idea can be extended to larger `limit` sizes.

In practice, I don't think that most databases implement this optimization when the limit is larger than 1.  Some may for the special case of `limit 1` (or `top 1` or whatever the right syntax is).

An index can be used for an `order by`.  In general, the columns in the index would need to match exactly the appropriate columns in the index.  SQL optimizers are generally not smart enough to recognize simple conversions.  On the other hand, people who write SQL usually don't do such transformations.

Comment: So, without index, even with LIMIT 1, the database will scan all rows, right?

Comment: @HanXu . . . The database has to scan all the rows (at least) to find the extreme value.  Otherwise, how would it know which is the biggest or smallest?